# Compare function to give a GArray when used with GString

Tags: c, data-structures, glib

i have a GArray with GString. My compare function goes as follows:

```
int compareProdutos (gconstpointer a, gconstpointer b)
{
    char* cast_a_pointer =  ((GString*) a)->str;
    char* cast_b_pointer = ((GString*) b)->str;

    return strcmp(cast_a_pointer,cast_b_pointer);
}
```

but it isn't sorting the array and is in fact, giving random results as the GArray ordering changes every time i run this code.
If i understand correctly, i need to give the strcmp function the "String" part of the GString and that is achieved by Gstring->str, so i'm not understanding what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: Your compare function looks totally fine but I will mention `GPtrArray` exists to hold pointers specifically.

Comment: what tingping said: show the code that creates the array and inserts the GStings to get more help -- I'm guessing you actually insert Gstring* (which is fine) but that means your compare function gets _pointers to_ GString*.